# How to get result of nodejs https.get result in json?

Tags: json, node.js, https

The url `https://mobileapp.mydomain.com/api/uuids?filter[where][uuid]=02644da038b37d7ba70b7ee1a92ba1d9`output is

```
[{"uuid":"02644da038b37d7ba70b7ee1a92ba1d9","date":"2017/10/05","time":"8:31:41","verified":false,"token":"null","id":"59d5bcb52f416812b0fc817a"}]
```

In following code `https.get`'s result is not json like and `process.stdout.write(d)`?

How can I get output in `json` format with less process.

```
const https = require('https');
var URL = 'https://mobileapp.mydomain.com/api/uuids?filter[where][uuid]=02644da038b37d7ba70b7ee1a92ba1d9';
https.get(URL, (res) => {
console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
console.log('headers:', res.headers);    
res.on('data', (d) => {
process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error('ERROR:',e);
});
```

**update output**
output of `process.stdout.write(d);` :

```
ClientRequest {
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: 
   { response: { [Function: bound onceWrapper] listener: [Function] },
     socket: { [Function: bound onceWrapper] listener: [Function: onSocket] },
     error: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  output: [ 'GET /api/uuids?filter[where][uuid]=02644da038b37d7ba70b7ee1a92ba1d9 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: mobileapp.mydomain.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' ],
  outputEncodings: [ 'latin1' ],
  outputCallbacks: [ [Function: bound onFinish] ],
  outputSize: 128,
  writable: false,
  _last: true,
  upgrading: false,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: false,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
  sendDate: false,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: 0,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  socket: null,
  connection: null,
  _header: 'GET /api/uuids?filter[where][uuid]=02644da038b37d7ba70b7ee1a92ba1d9 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: mobileapp.mydomain.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
  _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
  agent: 
   Agent {
     domain: 
      Domain {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        members: [] },
     _events: { free: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     defaultPort: 443,
     protocol: 'https:',
     options: { path: null },
     requests: {},
     sockets: { 'mobileapp.mydomain.com:443:::::::::': [Array] },
     freeSockets: {},
     keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
     keepAlive: false,
     maxSockets: Infinity,
     maxFreeSockets: 256,
     maxCachedSessions: 100,
     _sessionCache: { map: {}, list: [] } },
  socketPath: undefined,
  timeout: undefined,
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/api/uuids?filter[where][uuid]=02644da038b37d7ba70b7ee1a92ba1d9',
  _ended: false,
  res: null,
  aborted: undefined,
  timeoutCb: null,
  upgradeOrConnect: false,
  parser: null,
  maxHeadersCount: null,
  [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: { host: [ 'Host', 'mobileapp.mydomain.com' ] } }
> statusCode: 200
headers: { server: 'nginx/1.13.5',
  date: 'Thu, 05 Oct 2017 12:43:58 GMT',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '146',
  connection: 'close',
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Origin, Accept-Encoding',
  'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=0; includeSubDomains, max-age=31536000',
  'x-download-options': 'noopen',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  etag: 'W/"92-jcLXCzK/YpUyGdSTWS1c4YsxlvU"' }
[{"uuid":"02644da038b37d7ba70b7ee1a92ba1d9","date":"2017/10/05","time":"8:31:41","verified":false,"token":"null","id":"59d5bcb52f416812b0fc817a"}]>
```

Comment: try process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(d));

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work I got your Idea and used `d = JSON.parse(d);` but it seems reading a filed of returned record is taking so many time.

Comment: can you post what data comes in d variable so that anyone can help by seeing what type of data to convert to json

Comment: If the output isn't JSON, what _is_ it?

Comment: update of output added to end of question.

Comment: The JSON data is there (last line), it's just that you're _also_ using `console.log()` which is also writing to stdout.

Comment: These lines `process.stdout.write(d);
console.log(d[0].time);` returns **undefined**.

Comment: So what do you actually want to do? In your question you say you want to output the JSON (_string_) data, but from your comment it seems like you want to actually _parse_ it?

Comment: yes, actually without parsing d[0].time or any items are not easy to access.but parsing is take long time.